# Array of BufferedImages causes high memory usage

Tags: image, memory

I have an array of BufferedImages that takes up way more RAM than I would expect, or like, it too.  Here is the code:

```
public BufferedImage[] bufferVideo(String videoName, int framesToBuffer) {
    BufferedImage[] frames = new BufferedImage[framesToBuffer];
    for (int i = 0; i < framesToBuffer; i++) {
        String path = videoName + i + ".jpg";
        try {
            frames[i] = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return frames;
}
```

The frames are each about 175 KB on the disk. When I call bufferVideo(LionKing, 500), I expect the RAM usage to go up by 87.5 MB (or 175 KB * 500).  However, while watching my TaskManager, my program starts using about 1700 MB more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The images on disk are in the compressed JPG format, but the image in a `BufferedImage` is decompressed to its directly usable format (usually rgb24). A factor of 1:20 (roughly what you experience) seems quite spot on.

Your options include not reading all 500 files in advance, but only keep a much smaller cache of decompressed images and reading the others on demand in a producer-consumer pattern.

Comment: Oh thanks, that makes a lot of sense!  Could you explain what a producer-consumer pattern is?  Pulling the images from the disk when they were needed was pretty slow for what I am wanting, I was hoping by having them storeded in an array I could access them much faster.

Comment: What I ment with producer-consumer is: On startup create a background thread thad loads (and thus decompresses) the images into the Array, so that it contains N ready-to-use images. Then whenever you display an image (=consume it) remove it from the array and kick (=wakeup) the background thread, which will see there are now only N-1 images in the array and make the next one ready (=produce it). This way you always have a cache of ready images without the memory penalty of decompressing all of them.